# How do I make a VMWare VM not be running on a snapshot?

Tags: vmware-esxi, snapshot

I'm not sure I understand snapshots.  I took a snapshot of a VM on ESXi.  The Snapshot manager in VSPhere show the tree and at the bottom of that three is "You are here."  It is underneath the snapshots.  I only wanted the snapshot for a supplementary backup.

Why wouldn't "You are here" be at the top?  I never told it to run on snapshot x.  I need to be able to provision more space for the Virtual Disk but cannot because (I think) I am running on a snapshot.

Comment: Look for "The disk chain" in https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1015180 for an explanation of how this works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why wouldn't "You are here" be at the top?

It's just the way that snapshot manager displays the snap-tree is all.

If you're happy with where your VM is right now then just delete all snapshots and you'll regain all the delta-space that's been used. Also you shouldn't really leave snaps in place for more than about 48-72 hours - they're not a backup and leaving them in place, or having lots, can easily cause total VM corruption - they're for brief time periods ok.

Oh and why not go on some VMware training, it's not the simplest system to use and you could easily get yourself into trouble without some basic knowledge.

Comment: I guess it does make sense if you think about it.  It's saying it is the current and you can go back up the tree to previous "parents" or the older snapshots.

Comment: But does that mean I am "running on a snapshot"?

Comment: Yeah, exactly that, there's good reason for having the capability to have lots of snaps but the reality is that usually you do one before say a big upgrade/update then delete it once everything's fine. Anything more is possible but usually unnecessary.

Comment: While you have snapshots in place then yes you could say you're running on a snapshot yes - doesn't really mean anything but yes.

Answer (score 2):

A spapshot is a frozen system state that has been taken at some point in time. When you've got a snapshot on a VM, the snapshot is the parent to the current system state ("You are here").

You can't run the snapshot itself - even if you revert to a snapshot, you effectively delete the delta and start a new spawn off that snapshot with a new delta.

All snapshots and the current state are displayed in a tree structure since that's the easiest way to show dependencies - rolling back and creating new snapshots from there enables you to skip between them as you wish.

Deleting a snapshot integrates the parent data into the delta and makes it the current state (or the next lower snapshot), so you lose the snapshot to go back to. Deleting all snapshots integrates the chain the current delta depends on and you lose all other points to go back to. All other chains and snapshots are simply dropped.